# Can I keep a commit but remove all the changes?

Tags: git

Is there a simple way to revert all the changes of a commit but keep the commit itself? I have a lot of files in my commit, and most of them are generated. After a minor change all those files needs to be removed or reverted.

So the obvious way to do this is to git rm those files and git reset the ones that are not new files. But is there a faster way to do this? If I create a new commit on another branch and copy the change id will it become another patch for the same commit?

Edit:
To clarify I just want to undo the changes made to the current commit without checking out a new commit or creating a new one. I have posted an answer myself which takes the diff with the previous commit and either removes the files or reverts it depending on if they were newly created or modified. There might be a better solution however but this works for my use case.

Comment: `most of them are generated` ... auto generated files generally should _not_ be versioned by Git, because they aren't really original source code.  Also, what would be the point of having a commit with no delta whatsoever?

Comment: Are you looking for `git revert`? That creates a new commit which has the effect of undoing the changes make by another commit.

Comment: I already have the commit on gerrit and I would like to create a new patch on top of that with the new files. Yes most of the files are generated locally and need to be versioned. Whether that is a good idea or not is another topic

Comment: Can you be more specific what you mean by "keep the commit itself"? A commit is immutable, so once you've created it with changes, it's stuck that way. Are you looking to create a second commit that retains the commit message from the first commit but omits all of the changes? Or have you not even created a commit yet?

Comment: I have already created a commit and pushed it to gerrit. In my first patch I have created one json file. Running a script locally I have generated 8 more files, and 3 other previously files where modified as a result. So 12 files in total. Based on the comments I've got on gerrit I should add my changes in an existing json file instead of creating a new one.

So what I want is to get rid of the changes already commited. Edit the correct file, and generate the files again and upload a new patch to the same commit

Comment: So basically the opposite of git reset <other commit>. The changes are gone but the commit remains. It doesn't seem like there is any good way to do this other than manually removing those files and git resetting the modified files.

Comment: change the modified files (`git rm --cached`) and amend it to the last commit (`git commit --amend --no-edit`)

Comment: You can upload a new patch, but the commit you pushed will not change. You will just have a new commit that partially undoes the work of the previous commit. Is that okay? Or do you need to replace that commit with a new one? (In which case the `amend` option is what you want. But that creates a new commit, rather than editing the existing one. A commit is immutable.)

Answer (score 0):

In case, you don't want to commit modified files. You can take `git stash` into consideration.

- `git stash` to reset all files which have been modified or added to git.
- `git stash pop` when I want to restored files have been stashed.

In other hand, if you committed those files, you could use `git checkout`, `git reset` or `git revert`

Answer (score 0):

I found a decent solution. Running these two commands will restore all the changes in the commit without removing the commit.

`git diff-tree -no-commit-id --name-status -r HEAD | grep -oP '(?<=A).*' | xargs git rm`

`git diff-tree -no-commit-id --name-status -r HEAD | grep -oP '(?<=M).*' | xargs git checkout HEAD~1`

The first line removes all the added files and the second line restores the changes made to already existing files.

The first command `git diff-tree` returns the changes in the commit, option `--no-commit-id` removes the id and `--name-status` only returns the name of the files and the character that indicates if it is a new file, modified or a deleted file. The result is piped into a grep command that searches for either A or M (added or modified files) and returns the line excluding that character. Finally xargs transforms the output to arguments and then I perform the necessary git command on the files, `git rm` for added files and `git checkout HEAD~1` for modified files.